# VUEJS "Vue Hotel Datepicker" component

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuejs2, vue-component

This is the component I want to use [https://krystalcampioni.github.io/vue-hotel-datepicker/] [https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker#i18n] for date picker on my index.html but it is me giving an error **Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.** Below is the code I have written on my index.html`

```
//index.html
<html>
    <script src="path/to/vue.js"></script> 
    <script src="vue-hotel-datepicker/dist/vue-hotel-datepicker.min.js"></script> 
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <HotelDatePicker/></<HotelDatePicker>
        </div>
        <script>
            new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                components: { HotelDatePicker }
            })
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: you must use `require` for this

Answer (score 0):

If youre using a build tool, You must import the component before registering it with the vue instance

```
import HotelDatePicker from 'vue-hotel-datepicker'

new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       components: { HotelDatePicker }
 })
```

Otherwise use `require`

```
new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     components: {
          'vue-hotel-datepicker': require('vue-hotel-datepicker')
     }
})
```

Comment: i don't think this will work, browsers does not support `import`, which is a es6 syntax

Comment: Are you using a build tool to bundle your resources?

Comment: apparently he is not! (this is not my question). if he was using a build tool, then it would not be "wise" to even use dist version of this component library.

Comment: This is SO. Assuming "wise" decision making would not be "wise".

Comment: No, I'm not using build tool, its not scope of my project. Import also not working